# Jaxb generate one get method for all elements

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd

Part of my xsd file looks like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="group">
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="module" type="module" nillable="true" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>

    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>
```

When I generate my classes using Jaxb in Eclipse. The "Group" class generates a method called:

```
public List<JAXBElement<?>> getTitleAndDescriptionAndModule();
```

How do I change the xsd so that I get getter for each of the elements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAXB Types problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790118/jaxb-types-problem)